# compile same kernel driver multiple times

Tags: makefile, compilation, kernel, buildroot

I need to compile xyz kernel driver 2 times by passing a flag to use it as a configuration parameter in the source code. I need to generate the .ko files as xyz0.ko and xyz1.ko. Below is the required content from xyz kernel Makefile.

obj-m += xyz.o
xyz-objs = $(OBJECTS)

modules:

```
    for number in 0 1 ; do \
         CROSS_COMPILE=$(_CROSS_COMPILE) make ARCH=arm64 -C $(_KDIR) M=$(PWD) EXTRA_CFLAGS="- Dinst=$$number" modules ; \
          mv xyx.ko $(_INSTALL_MOD_PATH)/lib/modules/5.2.0/extra/xyz$$number.ko ; \
          rm -f $(OBJECTS) xyz$$number.* ; \
    done
```

But as per the above command every times i need to generate xyz.ko, rename xyz.ko to xyz$$number.ko and copy to target directory. Is there any way that directly i can able to generate "xyz$$number.ko" and install directly in the target directory.

If i use below command for installing .ko file to target, its installing xyz.ko not xyz0.ko or xyz1.ko

```
CROSS_COMPILE=$(_CROSS_COMPILE) make ARCH=arm64 INSTALL_MOD_PATH=$(_INSTALL_MOD_PATH) -C $(_KDIR) M=$(CURDIR) V=$(V) modules_install
```

I am calling "modules" from buildroot package.mk file

Kindly help me with your inputs

Answer (score 0):

How about simply creating xyz0.c and xyz1.c, each simply containing:

```
#define inst 0/1
#include "xyz.c"
```

And then just build each as a normal module?

Comment: xyz is not a simple module, it contains different sub-modules and around 50 source files, so i think your suggestion may not be considered. $(OBJECTS) contains obj files of all the source files. Any other feedback appreciated.